# Htaccess rewrite working but without query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite that works on localhost but not on my server. I'm trying to rewrite

```
www.website.com/arrangements/garden
```

to

```
www.website.com/arrangements.php?link=garden
```

and the code I have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^arrangements/(.*)/?$ arrangements.php?link=$1 [NC,L]
```

But what I get on the server is only `arrangements.php`. The query string `link` is not present. I've tried everything I could think of and contacted hosting support as well, they got nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Disable MultiViews (via `Options` directive), it often interferes with rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^arrangements/(.*) arrangements.php?link=$1 [L]
```